# The proper way to "merge" this situation

Tags: git

So this is what I have:

```
o experiments
|
o
|
o
|
o master
|
o
|
o (initial commit)
```

As you can see, I was working on the "master" branch for the first three commits. Then I created a new branch "experiments" to go in a different direction.

Now I'm facing this situation:

1. I've decided that my current "experiments" path is really the way to go.
2. However, there are still many files, and pieces of code within various files, from the old "master" that I deleted, but I want to bring back now.
3. Things have changed considerably. For instance, the directory structure of the working tree has changed considerably. This probably means that doing a regular git merge is not for me.

How should I deal with this situation? One idea is to ask this question:

- How should I checkout the old "master" into another directory (outside the current working tree), so I can do the merge myself, completely manually?

If you think this last question is the appropriate way to deal with this situation, please answer that one. Feel free to suggest other ways.

Comment: Has there been any development on the `master` branch? If not, then `git merge experiments` is a fast-forward on `master`.

Comment: Why do you think git cannot handle this? I do this all the time. Commit everything into experiment, checkout master, merge experiment into master. What he said ^

Comment: @AndrewFinnell But won't things mess up if I changed the folder structure, renamed files, added and deleted files, etc.? How can git possibly know the way I want to do this? Only some files I want back. Others I don't. And in others, I only wants parts of back. Hmmm.

Comment: Not entirely sure what your situation is (see @larsmans question, for example), but if you want to mix and match your patches, you might want to try `git rebase -i master` while on your `experimental` branch.

Comment: @JulienOster It's all just "linear", i.e. just that straight line depicted in the figure. The figure doesn't hide any details. So yeah, I haven't done any separate development on master.

Comment: @nooboverflow you can delete all the files in a branch and add a whole new hierarchy, commit it then merge. Git can handle that.

Answer (score 1):

> The figure doesn't hide any details. So yeah, I haven't done any separate development on master.

In that case a merge is as simple as it possibly can go. Git will make a fast-forward merge. That means that it will basically just set the `master` branch pointer to the same commit as your `experiments` branch is. There is really nothing else that happens.

And even if you diverged a bit on master, git will not just make a simple comparison of the tip of boths branches but actually look at what happened in the branches (by finding the common ancestor); this is known as a three-way-merge. So, it will *probably* figure out what you did and you probably won’t up with extreme merge conflicts. Of course there are always some exceptions but you’ll probably be able to figure those out easily when resolving the merge conflicts.

But again, as your `master` did not diverge at all, you can easily prepare your `experiments` branch the way you want it to look in the end and then fast-forward `master`. Alternatively, if you would like to make the history reflect the fact that you actually diverged (or at least planned to) from master, you can also force a merge commit using `git merge --no-ff experiments`.